# Div height is messed up

Tags: css, html

This is something I haven't experienced before, my div height isn't cooperating in CSS & is throwing off the whole flow of a page. The div is supposed to be centered, 960px wide, approx 1000px height & 150px of padding on the bottom to separate it from my footer.

Website Link: http://tinyurl.com/b8vvhgr

**HTML**

```
<div id="energyrating-desc">

<h1><span class="gray">Energy Audit Services</span></h2>

<img src="/nd/images/yellow-bar.jpg" width="960" height="2" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></img>

<p>According to the EPA Energy Star program, the average American household spends $1,500 annually on
energy bills - a number that may go up as much as 50% this year.
</p>

<br>

<p>Almost half of that energy goes to heating and cooling your home. Lighting and appliances represent about a
quarter of those costs. Each of us can take action today to reduce energy use at home, while still staying
comfortable.
</p>


<br>

<p>Let New Day Homes perform a top-to-bottom Energy Audit of your home to help determine the cause of any
problems you may be experiencing, help you gauge your home's energy efficiency, and recommend clear
steps you can take to reduce your energy bills.</p>

<br>

<p><b>Energy Audit</b></p>
<p>
Find out where you can save on energy costs by having a full energy audit done on your home.
</p>

<br>

<p><b>New home Certified Energy Ratings</b></p>
<p>
Performed for builders and home buyers.
</p>

<br>

<p><b>Ratings for Builder Tax Credit</b></p>

<br>

<p><b>Energy STAR Ratings</b></p>

<br>

<p><b>IECC-2009 Testing</b></p>
<p>
Blower door testing, insulation inspections, and pre-verification to meet the IECC-2009
Energy Code requirements.
</p>



</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*Energy Description*/

#energyrating-desc {    
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 670px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: You posted the correct CSS -- but it's not anywhere on your site.

Comment: your answer is your css, but your have defined it no where in your css

Comment: Got the problem fixed, thank you guys - dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i took a look in your css source, you have a `html` closeing tag in your `.css` take a look

```
body {
    /*background: url(/nd/images/bgtop.png), url(/nd/images/bg.jpg);
    background: url(/nd/images/bgtop.jpg)\9; /* IE 8 and below */ 
    background-repeat: repeat-x\9; /* IE 8 and below */ 
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;*/
    color: #000000;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

</body>
```

remove the

```
</body>
```

and i dont see `energyrating-desc` in any of your css

Edit:

Checked with firebug too just in case, you did not specify `energyrating-desc` in any of your css....

Comment: Thank you for the replies - I noticed that you guys have mentioned that there is no "energyrating-desc" included in the CSS, but I created a div id with that name, is that incorrect?

Comment: Got it fixed - nvm, stupid mistake (I forgot to update the .css path in my stylesheets).


Thanks again.

Comment: now its okay, i see it in your css, and dont worry when you code a lot sometimes this happens :) gave an upvote for your question, i hate it when someone down votes someone because of a mistake what they may do too sometimes and im happy if i was able to help, good luck in the future with codeing

Answer (score 0):

make your div in the centre by assigning proper margin.

```
margin:0 auto;

#energyrating-desc {    
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 670px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I reviewed the trace styles panel in the developer tools, there is not style attribute applied to the div element. Also I didn't find any style id named "energyrating-desc" in the css files of the website?! where did you define it? After all, I found that the html response of the `"energy.php"` has multiple `"html"` tags and an incorrect structure. You have to do that first before looking for a bug in the css styles.

An html document must have one root tag named `"html"`, one tag inside it named `"body"`, and if you needed, a tag named `"head"` for including css resources and meta tags or client scripts. Even one incorrect tag (unclosed, bad-written and ...) can cause many unbelievable layout you've never seen.

Cheers

Comment: Cheers, but I don't know who down voted me. As my experience says, the most of your problem is the html document and nothing else. ;)

Comment: you got a down vote (not from me) because the dash has nothing to do with this situation....

Comment: I know that, but my notation is different and it seemed buggy to me. :D Updated.